# Extracting Multiple Relation Triples from Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, extract

I'm trying to extract relation triples from Stanford CoreNLP, and it's working very well for single relation triples in a sentence but doesn't seem to work for multiple ideas in the same sentence.

For example: I drink water, and he eats a cake.

I would expect there to be two triples. (I, drink, water), (he, eats, cake), but only one will show up.

Here's what I'm currently working with:

```
with corenlp.CoreNLPClient(annotators="tokenize ssplit lemma pos ner depparse natlog openie".split()) as client:
      ann = client.annotate(text)
sentence = ann.sentence[0].openieTriple
for x in ann.sentence:
    print(x.openieTriple)
```

I would assume I"m doing something wrong here. Changing max_entailments doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: When I run on your example with the Java code I see 2 relations.  What version of Stanford CoreNLP are you using?

Comment: I"m using the python wrapper, and the latest corenlp downloaded from the stanford website. Every time I tried to run the sentence above I only got one relation.

Answer (score 2):

You must do:

```py
for x in ann.sentence:
   for triple in x.openieTriple
     print(triple)`
```

Discovered this today thanks to your question, so thanks!